# Testing equality of two functions in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to determine if the text of two different functions is identical?

```
x <- function(x) print(x + 2)
y <- function(x) print(x + 2)
identical(x, y)
[1] FALSE
identical(mget("x"), mget("y"))
[1] FALSE
identical(unname(mget("x")), unname(mget("y")))
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is a good method. It works for many different objects:

```
all.equal(x,y)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: ... and will also show the differences, should there be any

Comment: It's worth noting that `identical` provides more flexible control when comparing functions than the "deparse and compare" of `all.equal`. In R-devel, the "ignore.srcref" argument is added which -when set to TRUE- returns TRUE for `identical(x, y)`. This can be, also, achieved by removing attributes of "x" and "y" -- `identical("attributes<-"(x, NULL), "attributes<-"(y, NULL))`. `?identical` gives an example on the flexibility  on bytecompiled functions too; `identical(x, compiler::cmpfun(x))` VS `identical(x, compiler::cmpfun(x), ignore.bytecode = FALSE)` VS `all.equal(x, compiler::cmpfun(x))`

Answer (score 3):

Using `diffobj` package:

```
library(diffobj)

x <- function(x) print(x + 2)
y <- function(x) print(x + 2)

diffPrint(target = x, current = y)
```

[image]

Wrapping it in `any()` will give TRUE/FALSE:

```
any(diffPrint(target = x, current = y))
# FALSE
```