# R- Test equality of Function

Tags: r

I have `func1` and `func2`

I want to test whether I have put in `func1` or `func2` into another function `F`as an argument

```
F<-function(FUN){
   if(FUN==func1){
   #do this 
   }else if(FUN==func2){
   #do this 
   }else{
   #do this  
   }
}
```

Is there a way for me to check `FUN==func1` or `FUN==func2` so that it returns a logical TRUE or FALSE? This is obviously wrong because `==` cannot be used to test for function names

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567718/getting-a-function-name-as-a-string and see if that gets you where you want. If not, please expand the question with more detail!

Comment: Relevant post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39538431